# Используется ли во всех браузерах независимо от ОС перевод строки \r\n?

Tags: linux, windows, http, браузер, apple

Добрый день! Наткнулся на информацию, что в разных операционных системах перевод строки пишется по-разному:

Windows - \r\n

Apple - \r

Linux - \n

Но также где-то писали, что HTTP протокол независимо от системы использует \r\n.

Кому верить?

Comment: все правильно написано. Только нужно правильно читать - перевод строки "по умолчанию" в разных системах разный. А вот в каждом конкретном случае он может быть разный.

Comment: Т.е. вариант перевода строки у самой системы распространяется и на браузер?

Comment: браузер - слишком большая программа. Поэтому, в некоторых ее частях перевод может быть один, в других - другой. И иногда это бывает совсем рядом.

Comment: Получается есть смысл на сайте обрабатывать три варианта?

Comment: я не знаю, где именно и что именно Вы будете обрабатывать, но часто нужно быть готовым к дикой смеси переводов строк (но я не утверждаю, что они постоянно смешаны).

Comment: Понял, большое спасибо!

Comment: В хидерах всегда \r\n

Answer (score 5):

формат [**заголовков *http***](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8_HTTP) соответствует спецификации, изложенной в [rfc822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822).

согласно [секции 3.1.2 rfc822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822#section-3.1.2), поле заголовка должно заканчиваться двумя символами — [*возврат каретки*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8) (*carriage-return*, *cr*, в [*ascii*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) — шестнадцатиричное значение `0d`) и [*перевод строки*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8) (*line-feed*, *lf*, в *ascii* — шестнадцатиричное значение `0a`):

> Once a field has been unfolded, it may be viewed as being composed of a field-name followed by a colon (":"), followed by a field-body, **and  terminated  by  a  carriage-return/line-feed**.

---

в теле же сообщения (это может быть и *html-страница*, и вообще всё что угодно, например, просто бинарные данные), конечно, могут встретиться **любые** символы в любой комбинации.

Comment: В общем понял, лучше перестраховаться и проверить три возможных варианта. Спасибо за информацию!

Comment: @Jimmy, видимо, всё-таки не поняли. **в http-заголовках** может быть **только «один вариант»**. «без вариантов». а **в теле сообщения** может быть вообще **всё что угодно** — абсолютно любой набор произвольных байтов.

Comment: Ну так у меня как раз в блоке HTML-страницы и надо "отсеять" все переносы строк. Опять же, если я Вас правильно понял, то их проверять стоит, т.к. может быть любой вариант.